# ¿Cómo cambiar el background image por defecto SceneBuilder?

Tags: javafx

¿Es posible cambiar el background image que trae Scene Builder por defecto por una imagen personalizada?

[image: Background por defecto SceneBuilder]

Comment: Prueba a leer esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46270959/code-set-background-color-for-anchorpane-in-fxml-document

Comment: No me refiero a los componentes de JavaFX, sino al SceneBuilder como tal, es decir, la parte que está dentro del recuadro rojo: https://i.imgur.com/pv7snq5.png